# How can I make one canvas object collside with another canvas object using Tkinter?

Tags: python, canvas

So basically, I'm going to make a Brick Breaker type of game.  Just my beginning CS Python class didn't teach much OO programming, and I was wondering how I could make this free moving ball register when it hits the slider.  I think I have an idea, but I would like to see other peoples explanations.

Answer (score 0):

1. You know the position of the two objects that can collide and compute the distance. When this is smaller than a threshold then they collide
2. You use the Canvas.find_overlapping(*rectangle). to find out the figures on the canvas in a rectangle.

I always prefer option 1. It helps dividing model and presentation to the user which do not always need to be linked.